# parsing text to xml using xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

i need your support formatting the following sample text from its current format to xml format using xquery:
sample text to be parsed:

```
INTERNATIONAL MOBILE SUBSCRIBER IDENTITY = 001010000000597 TEMPORARY MOBILE SUBSCRIBER IDENTITY = N ACTIVATION STATUS = A
```

to be in the following xml format

```
    <item>
<paramName>INTERNATIONAL MOBILE SUBSCRIBER IDENTITY</paramName>
<paramValue>001010000000597</paramValue>
</item>
<item>
<paramName>TEMPORARY MOBILE SUBSCRIBER IDENTITY</paramName>
<paramValue>N</paramValue>
</item>
<item>
<paramName>ACTIVATION STATUS</paramName>
<paramValue>A</paramValue>
</item>
```

please any one can help me in such case,

Thanks

Comment: So which XQuery version, which XQuery processor do you use? If you have access to an XQuery 3 processor then see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-analyze-string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using XQuery 3.1 and the `analyze-string` function:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'xml';
declare option output:indent 'yes';

declare variable $input-string as xs:string external := 'INTERNATIONAL MOBILE SUBSCRIBER IDENTITY = 001010000000597 TEMPORARY MOBILE SUBSCRIBER IDENTITY = N ACTIVATION STATUS = A';

analyze-string($input-string, '(.+?) = (\S+)')//fn:match
!
<item>
    <paramName>{ fn:group[@nr = 1] => normalize-space() }</paramName>
    <paramValue>{ fn:group[@nr = 2] => normalize-space() }</paramValue>
</item>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kq

Using XQuery 3.0 without using the `=>` operator the question looks like this:

```
declare variable $input-string as xs:string external := 'INTERNATIONAL MOBILE SUBSCRIBER IDENTITY = 001010000000597 TEMPORARY MOBILE SUBSCRIBER IDENTITY = N ACTIVATION STATUS = A';

analyze-string($input-string, '(.+?) = (\S+)')//fn:match
!
<item>
    <paramName>{ normalize-space(fn:group[@nr = 1]) }</paramName>
    <paramValue>{ normalize-space(fn:group[@nr = 2]) }</paramValue>
</item>
```